# SQL Server windows NT

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 SQL Server Windows NT processes running and they consume the resources, I read that they are instances and if I'm not using some of them I should remove them, but I'm new to SQL Server and I don't know which instance I'm using.

How can I find out which instance I'm working on? and would deleting the folders in program files be enough cause I can't find them in apps & features?

Comment: Open `CMD` write `SQLCMD -L` and hit enter to know your instances, and follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup) article.

Comment: @Sami is it important to write like this?

Comment: You mean the question? if yes then [read this please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you need to be clear as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT @@servername` will give you `server/instanceName`

> Server: Is your sever name (Your machine name)
>
> InstanceName: is the instance installed

After you know which instance you are using (MSSQLSERVER in your case) follow **[this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup)** to uninstall other instances.

Comment: @Hadi Who encrypted before ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the process id from the windows task manager, and search it in the SQL Server logs. Follow this [Step by step article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2751/find-out-which-sql-server-instance-is-consuming-most-of-the-cpu/) for more information.

Also you can benefit from the `sp_Who2` and `sp_who` procedures:

From SQL management studio run `EXEC sp_Who`, and you will find the process that are using the instance.

Comment: i was thinking if i close them all and set the service to manual instead of auto and open sql server wouldn't that show me the one i'm using?

Comment: Yes, you're right i updated my answer, i misunderstood the question .

Comment: @Samerthestalker Are you looking for `SELECT @@servername`? or `SELECT @@servicename` mybe

Comment: @Sami i think he has 3 instances installed and he want to stop some instances. the 3 processes are `sqlservr.exe`

Comment: @Sami i don't know maybe, will try it

Comment: @Hadi That what I think fo a while, but it seems he want to know the instace name he worked on.

Comment: @Sami i tried @@servicename i dot mssqlserver, this mean i'm using this one?

Comment: @Samerthestalker Exactly yes

Comment: guys i have MSSQLSERVER, MSSQLSERVER01, MSSQLSERVER02 running in background, i just want to know which one i'm using in ssms

Comment: @Samerthestalker You have to use Sami suggestion

Comment: @Samerthestalker I rolled back my answer, also you can use `Exec sp_who2` to know which processes are running on the instance.

Comment: :) and yeah MSSQLSERVER usage increased, but one problem left how do i uninstall the other instances ?

Comment: @Samerthestalker follow the link tha Sami posted as comments under the question. Or you can just stop the services and set the startup mode to manual

Comment: @Samerthestalker i think you should accept Sami answer, also you can upvote it

Comment: :) ok you both helped can i write both as an answer?

Comment: @Samerthestalker No just upvote both and accept Sami answer.

Comment: @Samerthestalker https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work